# C# - Reflection.Emit: Return reference to a local variable

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamicmethod

I want to make a DynamicMethod which in turn behave like the following for example:

```
AnyClass myClass = new AnyClass();
Func<AnyClass> myFunc = () => myClass;
```

I know that when I want to make it work with an `int` instead of `AnyClass` I have to use the following snippet to return every time the number 12:

```
// Define method
DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod(
    "Name",
    typeof(int),
    new Type[] { });

// Define method body
ILGenerator il = method.GetILGenerator();
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 12);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

But now I ask myself how to do it with a not build-in class.

Edit:

At the end I want to get a reference from a local variable when I call the DynamicMethod. Look at the following snippet to better understand what I wanted to archieve. Here I want a func which returns on every call the variable I passed to the function which creates the func.

```
Func<AnyClass> GetMethodWithAFunc(AnyClass myClass) {
   Func<AnyClass> myFunc = () => myClass;
   return myFunc;
}
```

The generated IL Code for the snippet can be found on [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGFMDeqmJ2ArADwCCAdgJ64QCGAziwHyYDiApsALJ8AFgHsAJgHUwwIVRhkAFLQbM2mALYrWLAJSFipUvOr1G2zpvmYAvJgV7rFrWwDcBw9gDsGuvLcpDAF9UYJRUDGw4TGUzNiIA0hCgA). Unfortunately we have to provide a context where the data to return in the DynamicMethod could be saved. Finally I suggest a static cache and to use converting and unboxing when returning the values.

Comment: "But now I ask myself how to do it with a not build-in class." It's unclear what you mean here. You can't have a constant for a type that's not built into the CLR. It would help if you'd first show what the C# equivalent is for what you're trying to emit, then we can help work out how to emit the IL.

Comment: @JonSkeet Finally, I would like to know what the snippet is using the DynamicMethod to get the same result as the snippet I showed above which uses Func<>.

Comment: Ah, so not a constant, but a reference to a local variable. That's going to be tricky, because you'd need the context of the local variable. If you decompile the `Func` code you'll see the compiler creates a new class to hold all the context, then a method within that class. If you want a dynamic method to return a static variable, that would be much simpler. Please edit your question with more context - at the moment I doubt that an answer is really feasible.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, I think there is no way arround to generate this "extra" classes to provide the context right?

Comment: Well if you know that you're going to have *this specific situation* you could probably create a single generic class and reuse it. But we don't have much context of what you're trying to do or why you're using DynamicMethod.